# iOS orientation behavior on a landscape-only app

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, landscape, landscape-portrait

I am developing a landscape only application for the iPhone.

I have selected all 4 orientations on my Xcode project settings and I narrowed down my application's orientation in the main view controller by using the following delegate methods:

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Everything works as expected, except for the main iOS behavior: I want iOS to be able to show the Notification Center, every alert and the Control Center (on iOS 7 devices) while respecting the device's orientation, *without* rotating my application interface each time.

For example: When I hold my phone on portrait mode I want everything on iOS (Notification Center, alerts etc) to be presented in portrait mode with my app staying on Landscape Right mode.

Is that feasible?

As far as I know Apple does that in their applications, such as the default Camera app.

Is there a public method I can use to achieve that or is it part of a private API?